# Hide model classmember in controller in C# Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn and understand C# Web API and MVC.
I understand the simple tutorials where one has a simple Product or Person class as a Model and then makes a CRUD Controller to make use of the model.

But I need it to be a bit more complex and can't figure it out.

I have following Model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Same as the table in my database. The LastUpdated column has a default constraint: (GETUTCDATE())

I am not interrested in exposing LastUpdated in my POST methods in PersonsController:

```
 public void PostPerson(PersonModel person)
 {
     // Upload person to database
 }
```

Because then one could insert an invalid datetime in LastUpdated - or I have to manuel set LastUpdated in my business logic, but why not just let my SQL server do it?
Anyway to hide LastUpdated in PostPerson?
As a sidenote I would like to be able to show LastUpdated in my GetPerson method.
How is that possible?

Comment: In some cases you can use access modifiers, and you can also do it by restricting/sending only granted columns.

Comment: Hi Mehmood, how can I only choose which columns are granted?

Comment: Do you control communication to your WebAPI method?  I ask so that I might know what you passing in.  Just because your method takes a person, does not mean that all properties must be present.  Furthermore, you could clear the person.LastUpdated value prior to persisting the post to the database.  I'd recommend using stored procedures as well.

Comment: Please review my answer for better explanation.

Comment: @websch01ar stored procedures for inserting to database? I use Entity Framework, but I guess I could make procedures for the different inserts I need. Is it that what you mean? If so, why not just use EF to insert and save to DB?

Comment: I prefer to use them for my CRUD operations.  But then again, I am no longer a fan of EF.  I am hoping EF 7 has better/cleaner support for sprocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom DTO as a view model for the POST operation on this controller.  This would be additionally handy because you *probably* also don't want the client to supply the `Id` value either (I assume).  Something like this:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This would be the input for the controller action:

```
public void PostPerson(PersonDTO person)
{
    // Upload person to database
}
```

Then in the code you'd create a new `PersonModel` to add to the data context.  Something like:

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var newPerson = new PersonModel
    {
        Name = person.Name,
        Title = person.Title
    };
    db.Persons.Add(newPerson);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(Or perhaps create a kind of translation method on the DTO which returns an instance of the model, acting as a sort of factory method and putting the logic in the object rather than in the controller.)  This way the client isn't providing an entire `PersonModel` instance, just an object which describes the creation of that instance.  The GET operation can still return the full `PersonModel`.

When building an API (using WebAPI, for example) it can often be *really* useful to fine-tune the inputs and outputs like this.  And such custom DTOs/ViewModels really come in handy, albeit at the cost of slightly more code by creating essentially a translation layer to the backing models.

One tool I've found particularly handy in determining where in the API I need to tweak things is when using Swagger to generate my API docs.  Looking through the generated docs, I may notice something which I don't want to be exposed.  This is an indicator that I need to customize that API endpoint a little more so that the resulting docs are a little cleaner.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this. This will surely help me. Is this concidered to be a good practice? In my real life case I have several Models and to create multiple classes in each of them, containing almost the same properties.

Comment: @user1281991: There are pros and cons, to be sure.  Going down this path could potentially lead to a kind of "class explosion" where you end up with lots of similar classes, so keep an eye on the maintenance over time and make sure it's the right choice for your project. In general this pattern isn't uncommon, though. Often methods which act as factories or searches will accept a DTO as a parameter rather than many individual fields. This is just like that.  The POST operation is a kind of factory which accepts a *description* of an object and creates an instance. The DTO describes the object.

Comment: @David and if I need to get the Id from the model on GET request, I should create a PersonView? Or only a new PersonDetailDTO? Note: I am already using mapping.

Answer (score 3):

When you implement a property in a class, you can specify different access modifiers for the get vs. set accessors.

This is true whether you are implementing the property yourself, or using an automatic property.

Different combinations of access modifiers include:

**get/set both public** – client can read/write property value
**get/set both private** – client has no access to the property
**get public, set private** – property is read-only
**get private, set public** – property is write-only

```
// get/set both public
public string Name { get; set; }

// get/set both private
private string SecretName { get; set; }

// public get => read-only
public string CalcName { get; private set; }

// public set => write-only
public string WriteOnlyName { private get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand. Thank you very much for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the exclude attribute above the property

```
[Exclude]
public DateTime LastUpdated {get; set(}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, wouldn't that also exclude it from my GetPerson?

Comment: @user1281991 Sorry I missed that at first. You have a few options. You could create a viewmodel that includes the date on the get request and another viewmodel that doesn't have the date in your post request. That would prevent the date field from being bound in the post. Since none of these properties are marked as required you could also make the date field read only in the UI and not worry about posting it back on submit.